# insert into select for multiple columns, where only one column is from another table

Tags: php, mysql

Struggling on the correct SQL. Trying to insert data into a table, but need to insert only one of the columns from another table

```
INSERT INTO customer_details (user_id, firstName, lastName, email, mobile) 
VALUES (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?, ?, ?, ?, ?');
```

With a following "bind_param" function I will then assign variables to the question marks

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $username, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $mobile_num);
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the subquery in brackets? INSERT INTO customer_details (user_id, firstName, lastName, email, mobile) 
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?), ?, ?, ?, ?);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [13.2.5.1 INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html):

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    customer_details (user_id, firstName, lastName, email, mobile) 
SELECT id, ?, ?, ?, ? 
FROM users 
WHERE username = ?
```

Edit: check following example to understand how insert ..select works:

Create two tables: `one` and `two`

```sql
mysql> CREATE TABLE one (x int, y int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.58 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE two (x int, y int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)
```

Inserted some rows in table `two`:

```sql
mysql> INSERT INTO two (x, y)  VALUES (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 5), (6, 7);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.19 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM `two`;
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    4 |
|    3 |    5 |
|    6 |    7 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Table `one` is empty:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM `one`;
Empty set (0.02 sec)
```

Now, insert into table `one` where each `x` in table `one` == `y` in table `two`, and `y` in table `one` is equals to a value of variable (e.g. some data from user in script). Additionally, insert will be done if for `tow`'s row while condition is true.

```sql
mysql> SET @a = 100;  -- variable 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO one (x, y)  SELECT y, @a FROM two WHERE y IN (2, 4, 7) ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now table `one` is:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM one;
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
|    2 |  100 |  -- 100 is like value from use not from table `two`
|    4 |  100 |
|    7 |  100 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Works thanks! But I don't understand how you would distinguish between what variables come from what table, say I wanted 2 fields to come from users and the rest just as straight input.

Comment: @wazzaday ok I try to add an helpful example to explain.

Comment: @wazzaday check if it does helps. In your script `100` can be come from variable.

Comment: That clears it up for me, thank you for the detailed response! :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the `insert . . . select` form of `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO customer_details (user_id, firstName, lastName, email, mobile)  
    SELECT id, ?, ?, ?, ?
    FROM users
    WHERE username = ?;
```

Note that this changes the order of the arguments, because the comparison in the `where` is now last.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but try:

```
INSERT INTO customer_details (user_id, firstName, lastName, email, mobile) 
(SELECT id,?, ?, ?, ? FROM users WHERE username = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
INSERT INTO `customer_details` (`user_id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, `mobile`) 
SELECT `id`, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?

$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $first_name, $last_name, $email, $mobile_num, $username);
```